# How do I loop through json objects to get the data I want

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have json data and I want to get a specific object from the data. When I print `data._embedded.artworks[0]._links.thumbnail` in the console, I'm able to get the first thumbnail.

I'm wondering how I get all of the thumbnails. I tried

```
for (var key in data) {
    console.log(data._embedded.artworks[0]._links.thumbnail);
}
```

But here I also just get the thumbnails from the first id. I tried `artworks[key]` but I was not able to access other methods of the json data such as `_links`.

How would I loop through the json data to pull out all of the thumbnails?

Comment: `data._embedded.artworks.map(link => console.log(link.thumbnail))`

Comment: @MoisheSchwartz `.forEach` is better so this, as you are not actually `map`ping

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looping over `data`. You need to loop over `data._emebedded.artworks`. Try:

```
var art = data._embedded.artworks;
art.forEach(function(o){
  console.log(o._links.thumbnail);
});
```